# mongodb collections documents formtting

Tags: mongodb

Hi in my monogo collection contains following documents

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52398ba524c8b6f8a7c1cd96"),
"hostid":"127.0.0.1",
"application":[
{
"pid" : "50741",
"local_address" : "127.0.0.2:30501",
"user" : "hcsadm",
"pr" : "20",
"ni" : "0"
},
    {
"pid" : "50741",
"local_address" : "127.0.0.2:30509",
"user" : "hcsadm",
"pr" : "20",
"ni" : "0"
},
{
"pid" : "50741",
"local_address" : "127.0.0.2:30505",
"user" : "hcsadm",
"pr" : "20",
"ni" : "0"
}
]
 }
```

Now I want change above structure as below

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52398ba524c8b6f8a7c1cd96"),
"hostid":"127.0.0.1",
"application":[
{
"pid" : "50741",
"local_address" : [{"127.0.0.2:30501","127.0.0.2:30509","127.0.0.2:30505"}],
"user" : "hcsadm",
"pr" : "20",
"ni" : "0"
} ]
   }
```

Is there any way in mongodb to process this, I was tried update query but I was solve this issues if any one knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) it to the new collection

Comment: Using Map-Reduce above issue will be solve but I want to insert documents in same collections not creating new collections or I want update my documents it will possible in mongo Map-Reduce?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). MapReduce will also work, but you should generally prefer the aggregation framework for performance and usability purposes unless you are doing something specialized.

Try $unwind on the application field followed by $group on application.pid, application.pr, and application.ni.

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this "in place", so that the documents in the collection will be updated without creating a new collection.